# Excel SUMIF function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this Excel worksheet where I need to calculate the rates of transportation.

I have a table of rates for 2 types of lorries (big & small) to different destinations - all with different prices. Like this:

```
City    Big Lorry   Small Lorry
City A  1000        1150
City B  1800        1950
City C  2600        2750
City D  3900        3950
```

Now, in a different table, I want to enter the Lorry and the destination, and Excel should automatically fill in the price according to the above table. Like this:

```
City    Lorry   Price
City A  Small   
City D  Big 
City C  Big 
City B  Small   
City D      Small
City A      Big
```

Please see the link to OneDrive where I uploaded the Excel file so it's easy to understand what I need.

[Excel File](http://1drv.ms/1c3UCFD)

Thanks.

Comment: As the aim of this site is to provide answers that not only help you, but also help others with the same problem; can you please add full details of what you're trying to achive here rather than linking to your workbook?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I edited and tried to explain better. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Inscrutable, but it's really not any clearer. Are you just asking how to write a SUMIF formula?

Comment: @Inscrutable Write your input data into your question, as well as the expected outcome. Format it as code so that it is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one step with Excel, and you don't need SumIf.  Just use the following formula in your Price column `=VLOOKUP(A9,$A$2:$C$5,IF(B9="Small",3,2),FALSE)`.  This will look for the City value in your first column, then return the appropriate price based upon the lorry size.

This assumes (like your sample data) that there are only two prices (for large and small lorries) and that each City only occurs once in the second table.  If those assumptions aren't true, please update your example data.

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully copied the formula. However, there are only 2 prices indeed, but each city does occur more than once in the second table. I have updated the code above to reflect this. But even though the formula still works! Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

This is best done with a VLOOKUP but it'll be a little more complicated than your garden variety VLOOKUP as you're looking at two columns of data.

Although this can be done in one step it is less future proof, as if more sizes are added you'll have to update the formula and it could become quite unweildy.

**Step 1**
The VLOOKUP will need to look for a single value to find in the target table, but you're looking for two. To fix this you'll need a helper column, and because VLOOKUPS start at the left of the selected data range it will have to be the first column in your table.

- In your source table add a column to the left (make sure your table
  range includes the new column if you're using 2007>)
- Assuming this new column is in column A, and the size is in B and the
  destination is in C, add this formula to it, copying it down the
  range:

> =CONCATENATE($B2,$C2)

or

> =CONCATENATE([@Size],[@Distance])

*You could also do `=$B2&$C2` but this is easier for other users to understand*

- If you prefer, you can now hide this column

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**
Next it's time for the VLOOKUP.

Assuming the size is in A and the destination is in B, in the cell you want the value to be returned add this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A$2,$B$2),SourceTable,4,FALSE)
```

*If you're not using tables then replace SourceTable (or whatever you may have called it) with the source table's range. Note that the 4 represents how many columns across the value you want is.*

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could nest SUMIF inside of an IF statment.

```
=IF(B1="Big",SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A5,A1,Sheet1!B2:B5),IF(B1="Small",SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A5,A1,Sheet1!C2:C5),"Invalid Name"))

=IF(Size="Big",SUMIF(City List,City,Big Cost),IF(Size="Small",SUMIF(City List,City,Small Cost),"Invalid Name"))
```

A1 = City 
B1 = Lorry Size

Ideally in the source table I would have a column for size instead of two cost columns. That would allow SUMIF or VLOOKUP to work normally.
CityA Small 1500
CityA Large 1800
CityB Small 1350
CityB Large 1600